# Knockout Determining dropdownlist selection and update text to database

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working on binding some data retreive from database and then update it back to database. The database table is a bit weird in this case but I was given instruction to not modify the existing database.

The thing work as follow:
The database table contain both the GoldMemberCardNo and SilverMemberCardNo, in which only one of them is filled at a time (and another is null).

I am required to determine whether the member is GoldMemberCardHolder or SilverMemberCardHolder based on whether it is null and bind the correct one (both the member category and gold/silver card number) to the dropdownlist and text input on initial page load. **The one and only way i am able to differentiate whether the member is gold member or silver member is to see whether the CardNo is filled for the particular member**

The admin is then given permission to choose from the selection and enter the card number as they wish, and then submit the form.

Suppose, the user is previously an silver member card holder, and now is required to change to gold member card holder. After the admin fill in the required information, when update, the silver member card will be set to null and gold member card value is updated to database.

I have tried as following but getting stuck here. Since it is computed observable, the ko.observable will always be the same and will not listen to the changes when the value changes. Therefore, the value post is always the initial value. And i think my approach to this solution is pretty much bloated.

```js
function MemberProfile() {
  var self = this;
  self.SilverMemberCardNo = ko.observable();
  self.GoldMemberCardNo = ko.observable(); 
  self.CardNo = ko.observable();
  self.MemberCategory = ko.computed(function() {
      if(self.SilverMemberCardNo() != null) {
        return "0";
      else if(self.GoldMemberCardNo() != null) {
        return "1";
      }
  });
   self.CardNo = ko.computed(function() {
      if(self.SilverMemberCardNo() != null) {
        return self.SilverMemberCardNo();
      else if(self.GoldMemberCardNo() != null) {
        return self.GoldMemberCardNo();
      }
  });
  
  self.GetMemberProfile() = function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      url: ...,
      success: {
          ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
      }
    })
  }
  
  self.UpdateMemberProfile() = function() {
    if(self.MemberCategory == "0") {
      self.SilverMemberCardNo(self.CardNo);
      self.GoldMemberCardNo(null)
    }
    else if (self.MemberCategory == "1") {
       self.SilverMemberCardNo(null);
       self.GoldMemberCardNo(self.CardNo)
    }
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'PUT',
      url: ...,
      data: {
           SilverMemberCardNo: self.SilverMemberCardNo,
           GoldMemberCardNo: self.GoldMemberCardNo
           ......
      }
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MemberProfile());

// Data return from JSON
{
  "SilverMemberCardNo": null
  "GoldMemberCardNo": "123456789"
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="0" text="Silver Member" data-bind="value:MemberCategory"></option>
  <option value="1" text="Gold Member" data-bind="value:MemberCategory"></option>
</select>

<input type="text" data-bind="CardNo" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `MemberCategory` a simple observable and set it's value using your logic in the function of the `self.GetMemberProfile()` success event.

```js
function MemberProfile() {
  var self = this;

  self.CardNo = ko.observable();
  self.MemberCategory = ko.observable();

  self.GetMemberProfile() = function() {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'GET',
      url: ...,
      success: {
          ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

          if (self.SilverMemberCardNo() != null) {
              self.MemberCategory("0");
          } else if (self.GoldMemberCardNo() != null) {
              self.MemberCategory("1");
          }
      }
    })
  }

  self.UpdateMemberProfile() = function() {
    var silverMemberCardNo;
    var goldMemberCardNo;

    if (self.MemberCategory == "0") {
        silverMemberCardNo = self.CardNo();
        goldMemberCardNo = null;
    } else if (self.MemberCategory == "1") {
        silverMemberCardNo = null;
        goldMemberCardNo = self.CardNo();
    }

    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'PUT',
      url: ...,
      data: {
           SilverMemberCardNo: silverMemberCardNo,
           GoldMemberCardNo: goldMemberCardNo
      }
  }
}
```

Another thing to consider, which you may or may not be able to control, is that this logic would be more secure to execute on the server, instead of the client. Meaning take out all of that logic in javascript and do it on the server. Leaving the client to just present data and send it back.

Comment: +1 for `that this logic would be more secure to execute on the server`. It would also be simpler and available on initial page load instead of AJAX call.